# Dying Light the following: How to beat the Mother in final battle?

Tags: dying-light, dying-light-the-following

I am at the final part of **dying light - the following**. I have rejected Mother's request for sacrifice and fighting her.
But she is too fast and furious in the last phase - in seconds, I am dead. Especially, when she screams, my health goes to zero fast. Is there a specific strategy to beat her in last phase of battle?

Comment: I found a video with the fight: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DutQEpS5XcY. It looks like a pretty standard brawl with some running away.

Comment: Yes, that video makes this battle looks way easier, but it isn't actually! Reddit is filled with frustration about this battle.

Answer (score 3):

Found a working strategy after few tries.

1. **Clones:** First phase of battle with Mother is easy. She will have lots of her clones with her. Just stand on one of the square constructs in the area that has one side slanting. The clones will not climb from the slanting side, so just focus on stomping any clones that are trying to climb from steep sides. This phase will be over soon.
2. **Battle with mother:** This is also easy, if you follow exact steps.

a. When the battle starts, stay in the same are when you spawn. Mother will jump down and attack. DO NOT leave this empty area at any cost, NEVER run into the dark area at any cost.

b. Stand still. When Mother attacks, dodge one time and immediately attack her with punch. repeat until her health is 30% depleted.

c. If you get hit, run in circles or jump and run in circles till you fully regenerate your health.

d. After this she will become more aggressive. Start dodging 2-3 times instead on one and attack immediately after dodge. She may occasionally jump high in air and stomp, so dodge and attack after she lands. Follow c if you get hit.

e. After Mother's 80% health depleted, press required button and continuously hit the boss until a cutscene appears and game ends.

It could be frustrating, but completely doable.